# Twig Comments in web pages in symfony 4 displayed

Tags: twig, symfony4

i'm using symfony 4 with twig. And now I can see in all my web pages, that all twig comments are visible/displayed on the screen, when the page is loaded. But I don't know why this happens now. Can you help me?

Here is an image from my problem:
[Image from screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qq1u.png)

And here is the list of my used dependencies from composer.json:
"php": "^7.1.3",
"ext-iconv": "*",

"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",

"symfony/asset": "^4.0",

"symfony/console": "^4.0",

"symfony/debug-pack": "*",
"symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
"symfony/flex": "^1.0",
"symfony/form": "^4.0",
"symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
"symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
"symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
"symfony/orm-pack": "*",

"symfony/process": "^4.0",

"symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",

"symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
"symfony/validator": "^4.0",
"symfony/web-link": "^4.0",
"symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "^1.0",
"symfony/yaml": "^4.0"

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Bit vague. What do you mean with comments? Do you mean the `twig` syntax is visible instead of being parsed?

Comment: @Stef, Can you show your error in image or pic link?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev: Added image in my description

Comment: @DarkBee: You can see my problem in the image

Comment: Comments with `twig` are done with [`{# comment #}`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#comments)

Comment: @DarkBee: If you see my example you see that the comment `{# comment is printed #}` is printed.And this shouldn't be. And i'm wondering why.

Comment: If see `<# comment #>` and not `{# comment #}`, as u did not provide your twig file I could only assume u use `<#` and not `{#`

Comment: You've right. That's it!